# Remove part of folder name in bulk that’s inside a specific directory

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file, rename

In my "C:\image\Test_Directory\" i have various folders named {hello1, hello2, hello3, hello4} etc... I wanted to remove the word hello in my folders under my "C:\image\Test_Directory\"  so the folders would read {1, 2, 3, 4} etc... I searched online on how to do this but i had no luck.

**Example Issue:**

[image]

**GOAL:**

[image]

Comment: [sure you did](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23+rename+folder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use `Directory.Move()` to rename the folders:

```
foreach (var dirName in Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\image\Test_Directory"))
{
    string newName = dirName.Replace("Hello", "");
    Directory.Move(dirName, newName);
}
```

Comment: Good but what if other parts of the path contains the word to be replaced, it would end up on a different place ?

Comment: @Aybe True, but the OP gave the specific path they're using, which doesn't include "Hello".

Comment: So you're kind of lazy to post a solid answer ;)

Comment: Thank you, its much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Use RenameDirectory() function 
Try this :

```
 Dim dir As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("C:\image\Test_Directory")
    Dim folders As DirectoryInfo() = dir.GetDirectories()
    For Each folder As DirectoryInfo In folders
        My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameDirectory(folder.FullName, folder.Name.Replace("Hello", ""))
    Next
```